# get bitcoin cash address from public key, using bitcoin-abc

Tags: public-key, cryptocurrency, bitcoin-abc

hey i am using https://github.com/Bitcoin-ABC/bitcoin-abc and trying to get bch adress form ecdsa public key.

I have this compressed public key:

```
     publickKey = "02c0fe3501b514b1b2136b4d923de0907314a7c92499fd29a0cb7cf9f731711a19"
```

This is its bitcoin address: "39n8cpkeHhJDzhTVkboagHMbr9WYSLv2Yk"

And according to https://cashaddr.bitcoincash.org/ this is its bitcoin-cash address: "bitcoincash:ppvt3t9zkp3flgvgunp0wpp6l9t9tc85kvhtg5zkvr"

i tried to get the bch address like this:

```
    const auto netParams = bCreateChainParams(bCBaseChainParams::MAIN);
    CTxDestination dst = CKeyID(uint160S(publickKey));
    std::string encoded = EncodeCashAddr(dst, *netParams);
```

and i get different bitcoincash address (and not the one above)

i also tried:

```
    std::vector<uint8_t> hashVector = std::vector<uint8_t>(uncompressKey(publickKey));
    bCashAddrContent keyContent{PUBKEY_TYPE, hashVector};
    string encoded = EncodeCashAddr("bitcoincash", keyContent);
```

when uncompressKey function uncompressing the ecdsa key and removes the headres from it.

i also tried with SCRIPT_TYPE instead of PUBKEY_TYPE, yet i dont get the right address....

i also cant find any example code

any idea?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - This appears to be a programming question. Programming questions are off-topic here, even if they are about cryptography programs/libraries. Programming questions belong on stackoverflow. I can migrate this there for you.

Answer (score 1):

i succeeded to get to the Compressed  Bitcoin Cash Address:

```
CPubKey cPubKey = CPubKey(hash.begin(), hash.end()); 
auto dst = GetDestinationForKey(cPubKey, OutputType::LEGACY); 
std::string encoded = EncodeCashAddr(dst, *netParams);
```

when "hash" is std::vector of the compressed public key (66 characters) and "encoded" is Bitcoin Cash Address Compressed

if someone knows how to get the regular address (uncompressed) please let me know